# Strange error importing library in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, amazon-web-services

Xcode refuses to recognize a library I have in my Xcode project. Here's a google docs that shows the problem detailed in several images; I feel this is the way to convey the problem. Thank you. Here's a link to the images: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ZnOLtNtAPfSEf_c8l9G6iNYA9RnlFEAUYzH-YAb0KcU/edit?usp=sharing

Note that even if I change the import statement to #import "AWSS3/Services/AWSS3TransferManager.h" instead of #import "AWSS3/AWSS3TransferManager.h" this doesn't fix it. You may notice, of course, that the error message has nothing to do with the above lines, but if I add the above lines then the error message pops up. It looks like all the libraries are in the right places!
Be sure to scroll down in the google doc to see all 3 images. Let me know if there's anything else you need to see!

Answer (score 0):

It seams you have created folder reference.(Folder colors are blue in your image)

You should create groups while dragging files to xcode project. (This blue folders will be yellow after this)

See this image:

[image]

Another thing:

When you try to import files with reference use `#import <abc/abc.h>` instead of 
`#import "abc/abc.h"`